# A shell command for composing a file from chunks of another file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

I have a data file and a file containing a list of positions and I want to generate a file from chunks of the data file. Example:

```
$ cat data
abcdefghijkl
$ cat positions
0,2
5,8
$ cutter positions data
abcfghi
```

Is there a (linux) shell command that works like my hypothetical "cutter"?
The particular format for "positions" is not important.
We can assume that the chunks specified in "positions" are in increasing order and do not overlap.
There might be an additional "cutter" mode where the positions count lines not bytes.

I could implement such a program myself easily but I have the gut feeling that such a program already exist.

Comment: I should add that the data file is usually about 100 MB and contains multiple lines. The positions file may list 10000 chunk positions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just using bash's substring extraction from parameter expansion, and using the `positions` file format as given:

```
data=$(< data)    # read the entire file into a variable
while IFS=, read start stop; do
    printf "%s" "${data:$start:((stop-start+1))}"
done < positions
echo
```

outputs

```
abcfghi
```

If your data file spans multiple lines, you will have to take care with the positions file to account for the newline characters.

This method does not require you to read the data file into memory:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 3<data
exec 4<positions
pos=0
while IFS=, read start stop <&4; do
    ((nskip = start - pos))
    ((nkeep = stop - start + 1))
    ((pos += nskip + nkeep))
    ((nskip > 0)) && read -N $nskip <&3
    read -N $nkeep <&3
    printf "%s" "$REPLY"
done
echo
```

Answer (score 3):

`cut -c` will allow you to specify fixed width columns, which seems to be what you're looking for:

```
$ echo "abcdefghijkl" | cut -c 1-3,6-9
abcfghi
```

Note that the character positions start at 1 rather than 0. Individual columns may be specified using commas, e.g. `cut -c 1,3,5,7`, or ranges can be specified using a dash: `cut -c 2-8`

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with `cut` as [Barton Chittenden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14111700/a-shell-command-for-composing-a-file-from-chunks-of-another-file/14112461#14112461) points out with the addition of command substitution:

```
$ cut -c $(cat positions) data
abcfghi
```

> The particular format for "positions" is not important.

I made the format of positions as expected by `cut` so no extra processing was required.

```
$ cat data
abcdefghijkl

$ cat positions
1-3,6-9
```

---

You can turn this into the `cutter` command by adding a [function](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/functions.html) in your `~/.bashrc` file

```
function cutter ()
{
     $ cut -c $(cat "$1") "$2"
}
```

Run `source ~/.bashrc` then you can use `cutter` as required:

```
$ cutter positions data
abcfghi
```

Use redirection to store the output in a `newfile`:

```
$ cut -c $(cat positions) data > newfile

$ cutter positions data > newfile
```